# Returning only duplicate rows from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Every thread I've seen so far has been to check for duplicate rows and avoiding them. I'm trying to get a query to only return the duplicate rows. I thought it would be as simple as a subquery, but I was wrong. Then I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM a
WHERE  EXISTS
(
     SELECT * FROM b
     WHERE b.id = a.id
)
```

Was a bust too. How do I return only the duplicate rows? I'm currently going through two tables, but I'm afraid there are a large amount of duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean duplicate?   A row that exists in both tables or a row that appears in a single table twice?   Also is it a duplicate if only the id is the same, or do all the other columns need to be the same too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure your posted code would work too like

```
SELECT * FROM a
WHERE  EXISTS
(
     SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE id = a.id
)
```

You can as well do a `INNER JOIN` like

```
SELECT a.* FROM a
JOIN b on a.id = b.id;
```

You can as well use a `IN` operator saying

```
SELECT * FROM a where id in (select id from b);
```

If none of them, then you can use  `UNION` if both table satisfies the union restriction along with `ROW_NUMBER()` function like

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS rn
FROM (
select * from a

union all 

select * from b) xx ) yy
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

use this query, maybe is better if you check the relevant column.

```
SELECT * FROM a

INTERSECT 

SELECT * FROM b
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** there's an ambiguity as to what you mean by a duplicate row, and whether you're talking about duplicate keys, or all fields being the same. My answer deals with all fields being the same; some of the others are assuming it's just the keys. It's unclear which you intend.

You might try

```
SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
  WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2
```

adding in other columns as necessary. The database engine should be intelligent enough to do the comparisons on the indexed columns first, so it'll be efficient as long as you don't have rows that are different only on lots of non-indexed fields. (If you do, then I don't think anything will do it particularly efficiently.)